# How can i alias a column in SOQL?

Tags: soql

I am doing a select from SOQL :

```
   SELECT COUNT(Id) recordCount FROM Account
```

I would expect the result to have a column name of recordcount , but instead it has Count(Id)
How can i make the column name as recordcount and not the result of the aggregation from it's default expr0 to recordCount ?

Comment: COUNT(Id)  AS recordCount

Comment: I have tried SELECT COUNT(Id) AS recordCount FROM Account , it gives an error , Unknown error parsing query